# Iphone reload tableview after a purchase has finished gives odd error. " error: expected ':' before '.' token"

Tags: iphone, uitableview, in-app-purchase, reloaddata

Guys I'm using the code below. Xcode refuses to compile the last line. I get:

"error: expected ':' before '.' token"

on the last line. Can't figure out what is wrong...

```
- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{   
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)      
    {       
        // Optionally, display an error here.       
    }   
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [SelectorController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your `SelectorController` is a class, not an instance of a class?

Comment: So you are saying it should be something like:

SelectorController *selector;
[selector.tableView reloaData];

Comment: I'm saying you should first get yourself an instance of `SelectorController`, by alloc-init-ing one, or by getting one from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, what is a `SelectorController`?  Given the CamelCaseCapitalization, it looks like it's a class name.  Perhaps somewhere else in your code you have a line that defines an instance of the `SelectorController` something like this:

```
SelectorController * selectorController;
```

In which case (pun intended) the problematic line should be:

```
[selectorController.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks but have already tried this. But this has given me an idea.